# How to create a custom function with specific parameters

Tags: r, function

I am working with a large dataframe that has about 8,000 observations from 19 survey sites and 10 survey seasons (total 190 surveys).

I need to calculate the column means for each survey. I can go through each individually, but I would like to make a function that can compute the column means all at once.

See below the function:

```
newFunction<- function(df, x = "survey", y = "survey_site_number", a = 1, b = 1){
  repeat{
    for (x in "season") {
      if(x == a){
        repeat{
          if(y == b){
            rbind(c(1:10, colMeans(df[,c(11:161)])))
          } b <- (b+1)
          if(y>19){
            break
          }
        }
      }a <-(a+1)
      if(x>10){
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this ends up with the following error:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"          if(y == b){
            colMeans(df[,c(11:161)]))"
```

What I would like is to create a function that will give me a row with the first ten columns of metadata, the means of the remaining columns for specific rows and to repeat that process for all values of `x` and `y`.

```
structure(list(season = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), survey_site_number = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), Acanthastrea = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Acanthophyllia = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acropora = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
12L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 24L, 0L, 4L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There are many errors in your function. 1) in `for (x in "season")` the loop control variable `x` takes only the value `"season"`, which is a constant character string; 2) where is the `else` in `} b <- (b+1)`?; 3) the same for `} a <- (a+1)`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. With so many columns, you could also select only the relevant columns, (surbey, survey site number and 2 or 3 survey answers columns, not `11:161`, say `11:13` are enough).

Comment: Maybe `agg_cols <- c("survey", "survey_site_number"); surv_cols <- 11:161; aggregate(df[surv_cols], as.list(df[agg_cols]), mean, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Hello.  The line you quote has two opening braces `(` and three closing ones `)` hence the error.  That said, I think you'd be much better off pivoting longer then doing grouped operations to get the mean.  Check here:  https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Comment: @RuiBarradas i have used dput to give a smaller dataframe, thank you for your help

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen thank you, ill have a read and try to understand pivoting

Comment: Just `aggregate(. ~ season + survey_site_number, df, mean)`.